# Is it possible to install qt5 on ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-10.04

I am using ubuntu 10.04 LTS is there a way to install qt5 on it , I google it but I could not find a perfect solution ?

Comment: Did you try it?